# JSP page javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: jsp, properties, javabeans, propertynotfoundexception

My view model looks like this:

```
public class HomePageViewModel {
    private List<AlertViewModel> alertViewModels;
    public List<AlertViewModel> getAlertViewModels() { 
        return alertViewModels;
    }
    public void setAlertViewModels(List<AlertViewModel> alertViewModels) {
        this.alertViewModels = alertViewModels;
    }

    public HomePageViewModel(){
        alertViewModels = new ArrayList<AlertViewModel>();
    }
}
```

AlertViewModel looks like this:

```
public class AlertViewModel {
    private String id;
    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public AlertViewModel(){
        id = "";
    }
}
```

JSP looks like this: (viewModel is a HomePageViewModel)

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    </tr>

    <c:forEach items="${viewModel.AlertViewModels}" var="alert">
      <tr>
      <td>${alert.Id}</td>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>    
</table>
```

But I get this error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /. Reason:

Could not find property AlertViewModels in class viewmodels.HomePageViewModel
Caused by:

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find property AlertViewModels in class viewmodels.HomePageViewModel
```

What am I doing wrong? I think I have the get/set correct right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getter name is `getAlertViewModels()`, so you should be referencing `alertViewModels` (lowercase A).